# Mongodb aggregation in Nodejs and express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

The below aggregation is working in mongo db, but when i tried to integrate this with node js to get the count value through `API`, its returned null value

I am currently finding out ways to do `Aggregation` in `Node js`.

Below are the integration code with node js

```
   app.get('/count', (req, res) => {
      var name = req.params.name;

      adpostdata.aggregate([
        { "$facet": {
          "Total": [
            { "$match" : { "category": { "$exists": true }}},
            { "$count": "Total" },
          ]
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "Total": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Total.Total", 0] },
        }}
      ], (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
       res.send(result+"")
    })

      })
```

my input is

```
{
category :"dress"
}
{
category:"cars" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for your help, now i am able to get my excepted outputs

app.get('/count', (req, res) => {

```
  adpostdata.aggregate(
    [
      // Count the number of books published in a given year
      {
        $facet: {
          "categories": [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$category',
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      // Sort by year descending
      { $sort: { count: -1, _id: -1 } }
    ],

    "Total": [
      { "$match" : { "category": { "$exists": true }}},
      { "$count": "Total" },
    ],


  }}]).toArray( (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(result)
   res.send(result)
})

  })
```